# Avoid Ctrl being inserted when creating a shortcut key in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm trying to set `Alt + M` as shortcut key for Notepad++ but when I press the combination I automatically get `Ctrl` at the beginning of the shortcut (as shown in the picture).

I tried clearing the input by pressing the Windows key, which leads to the value being set to **None**. But pressing `Alt+M` still results in the value `Ctrl + Alt + M` being set.

[image]

Comment: The alt key by itself is reserved.  It dates back to the before times when windows was new and dinosaurs roamed the earth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make shortcuts and make it customisable, there's 2 options (that i know of, and have worked for me)

Both involve applications, namely:

- Powertoys by Microsoft
- AutoHotKey (AHK)

Both are used for making shortcuts and are fairly straightforward, they're also full free, and the latter is open source (not sure about the former)

1. For Powertoys, one of its options is KeyboardMapper, you can make any type of shortcuts or change shortcuts to perform different functions
2. For AHK, the app runs as a small script in the background and can be added to the startup app list by using Win+R and opening shell:Startup and copy pasting the script in the Startup folder